# generate more than one random code in laravel and save it to database

Tags: laravel, random, generate

I'm a newbie in laravel. I have to generate multiple random characters at once in my laravel project and then save them to database. Any example or advise that quite easy to understand? thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far…?

Comment: SO is not a place for tutorials. Check out for some tutorials online you will probably solve this yoursefs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop may be appropriate for you in this case. If you don't have an object for the codes, you can do something like this:

```
$total_wanted = 100;
for ( $i = 0; $i < $total_wanted; $i++ ) {
    DB::table('codes')->insert(['code' => uniqid("prefix")]);
}
```

If you do have a Code object, you can do it like this instead:

```
$total_wanted = 100;
for ( $i = 0; $i < $total_wanted; $i++ ) {
    $code = new Code;
    $code->code = uniqid("prefix");
    $code->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo uniqid('code_', true);
```

You generate a random, unique string based on current timestamp, so it can not be a duplicate.

Then simple store it in the database as a `varchar`

More about this function [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)